# .htaccess only protecting folder sometimes

Tags: apache, .htaccess, .htpasswd

#### Website

https://ochab.us

#### Desired behaviour

When you click on any of the projects on the homepage, for it to require a password before taking you to that page.

#### Actual behaviour

If you go directly to the project page (https://ochab.us/work-locked/security-platform), it requires a password. This is correct.

If you go to https://ochab.us and right click, "Open in a new Tab" on one of the projects, it requires a password. This is also correct.

If you go to https://ochab.us/ and click on a project it somehow skips the password protection. This is the issue I'm trying to fix.

#### The code

I have a site structure setup like this:

```
/index.html
/work-locked/project-1/index.html
/work-locked/project-2/index.html
/work-locked/project-3/index.html
/work-locked/project-4/index.html
```

I set up `/work-locked/.htaccess` to look like this:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Please message me via my contact page to get access."
AuthUserFile /my-path/.htpasswd
require valid-user
```

I wondered if the password was cached, but I've tried it in different browsers and via BrowserStack and the same result.

MediaTemple is my host.

Thanks!

Comment: "click on a project it somehow skips the password protection" - When you click directly on the link there is no external request for `/work-locked/security-platform` (only a bunch of images in `/_nuxt/img/`). So the relevant content would seem to have already been loaded in a different way? Only when you "open in a new tab" or paste the link directly into the browser is there actually an external request to  `/work-locked/security-platform` (which then triggers the Apache auth).

Comment: This worked! I updated the links from:

```<a href="/work-locked/project-name">``` to ```a href="//ochab.us/work-locked/project-name">```

It's going to make developing locally a bit of a pain, but since this is a pretty small project I'm okay with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up updating the links from: `<a href="/work-locked/project-name">` to `<a href="//ochab.us/work-locked/project-name">`

It's going to make developing locally a bit of a pain, but since this is a pretty small project I'm okay with that.